# Coloring half of a single frame in black

Tags: beamer, color

I'm currently working on a presentation using the `beamer` class and I've stumbled upon a problem that I don't know how to solve. Consider the follwoing MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}} 

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, mathtools}

\usefonttheme{serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Useful relations to keep in mind}
\begin{align*}
A&=B+C& U&=\psi(x)\\
G&= AA& C&=\partial^\nu\\
B&=A+B& F&=BB
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This gives
[image]
but I'd like it to be
[image]

I'm honestly a bit lost at how one could achieve this since I never had to work with "filling" things in Latex with color...

**EDIT:** Just to make it clear, this should only apply to one frame, all other frames should stay normal!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Off-topic: you don't need `graphicx` with beamer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome. How about

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}} 

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, mathtools}

\usefonttheme{serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Useful relations to keep in mind}
\begin{align*}
A&=B+C& U&=\psi(x)\\
G&= AA& C&=\partial^\nu\\
B&=A+B& F&=BB\tikzmark{aux}
\end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\fill ([yshift=-1ex]pic cs:aux) coordinate (aux) (current page.south west) rectangle 
(aux-|current page.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can, of course, move the equations up and it still works.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}} 

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, mathtools}

\usefonttheme{serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Useful relations to keep in mind}
\vspace*{-3em}
\begin{align*}
A&=B+C& U&=\psi(x)\\
G&= AA& C&=\partial^\nu\\
B&=A+B& F&=BB\tikzmark{aux}
\end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\fill ([yshift=-1ex]pic cs:aux) coordinate (aux) (current page.south west) rectangle 
(aux-|current page.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer! This is very close to what I'm looking for... Would it be possible to shift the `align` environment up a bit (closer to the title) and fill the rest with black?

Comment: @MariusJaeger Of course. I added a version that does that.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much!